# Java Ignoring an Exception and Continuing Loop

Tags: java, exception

I have a program where it checks if a given URL is real multiple times, each with different URLs. I have a for loop set up:

```
for (int i=0;i<100;i++) {
    URL url=findWebsite();
    System.out.println(readURL(url));
}
```

But when it encounters a URL that does not exist, it just throws a Runtime error and stops the program. I tried putting a try and catch around the loop:

```
try {
  for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
    URL url=findWebsite();
    System.out.println(readURL(url));
  }
} catch (Exception e){

}
```

The problem is: even though it doesn't stop the program, it exits the for loop. So how can I make it to continue the for loop when it encounters a runtime exception?

Thanks

Comment: You can use any formatting/indentation style you like in your own code, but when asking for help, it's best to use some reasonable, common style -- such as indenting the contents of each block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the `try/catch` **inside** the loop:

```
for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    try {
        URL url=findWebsite();
        System.out.println(readURL(url));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

---

Side note: Normally, silently ignoring exceptions is suspect, but there are some use cases.